# Jquery uncheck radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be the right code but its not working

```
<input type="radio" name="test">1
<input type="radio" name="test">2

$('input[name=test]').click(function() { 
    $('input[name=test]').attr(‘checked’,false);
});
```

example here

http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/16/

EDIT:

I forgot the line that should say if its checked then uncheck it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? According to your code it would not check anything when you click them, but if that's your goal then you should just add the `disabled` property. Can you give more detail about your end goal.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to give those two radios the "disabled" attribute? (edit: heh seems Seth and I have the same impression ;)

Comment: uncheck which?  You appear to be asking for a click on either checked element clearing the check on _both_ ?

Comment: I need the radio buttons to be checked either 1 at a time or if a already checked button it clicked then it unchecks

Comment: @Lee unchecks _both_ or just that one?  If the latter, no code is needed!

Comment: Radio buttons don't uncheck as standard

Comment: @Lee right - was confused by all the talk of 'checking'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `.attr` to `.prop` and it will work fine. You will also need to change the quotes you are using around "checked" to be the right type, as that is also causing it to break at the moment:

```
$('input[name=test]').click(function() { 
    $(this).prop('checked',false);
});
```

You can see this working in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/22/).

**Update** (based on comment)

Now that I actually understand what is required, a different approach is needed. You need to remember the previous value of the `checked` property, by storing it in an attribute:

```
$('input[name=test]').click(function(e) { 
    var previous = $(this).attr('previous');
    if(previous){
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
    }
    $(this).attr('previous', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

See this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/39/).

**Update 2** (based on further comments)

The above code from the first update does not quite work, because when clicking a different radio button in the set, the `previous` attribute of the previously checked radio remains set, but the radio is not actually checked. We can avoid this as follows:

```
var previousElem;
$('input[name=test]').click(function(e) { 
    var previous = $(this).attr('previous');
    if(previous && previousElem === this){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    previousElem = this;
    $(this).attr('previous', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I posted this because the example fiddle from the question was set to use 1.6.

Comment: Sorry i need it to uncheck only if its checked

Comment: @Lee - see my update, if I now understand you correctly, that should do the trick. Again note that it will require jQuery 1.6+ though, as it uses the `prop` function.

Comment: @James this has the same problem as the fiddle I'm working on - if you click on the _other_ button when the other one just became deselected sometimes the click is ignored.

Comment: @Alnitak - Good spot, I didn't notice that! Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: @James it's tricky because the button that _loses_ the selection doesn't get any events when that happens

Comment: @Alnitak - See my update. It seems to work quite well... here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/49/

Comment: @Alnitak - You got it 19 seconds before me! I prefer your method though; it doesn't use a global variable. I was going to carry on working on it to improve it, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @James - Your final solution works in 1.6.0 **but not in jQuery 1.6.4.** Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the 'checked' property if using jQuery 1.6+

```
$('input[name=test]').filter(':checked').prop('checked', false);
```

For earlier versions:

```
$('input[name=test]').filter(':checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

**EDIT** to fix the OPs *actual* problem, i.e. how do you make *all* radio buttons in a set unchecked when the currently selected button is clicked, this works (in Chrome 12, at least):

```
$('input[name=test]').click(function(e) {

    // find out whether it was already checked
    var wasChecked = $(this).data('checked') || false;

    // ensure all buttons think they're unchecked 
    $('input[name=test]').data('checked', false);

    if (wasChecked) {
        // leave them all unchecked
        this.checked = false;
    } else {
       // just check this one
       this.checked = true;
       $(this).data('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/qHepU/

Comment: Sorry i need it to uncheck only if its checked

Comment: @Lee your original code didn't mention that - answer updated to reflect this. NB: `.filter(':checked')` is preferred over $(':checked') - see http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: YEs sorry i forgot that bit....i just tried that line and it doesn't let me check it at all...

Comment: @Lee you need to be much clearer about what you're trying to achieve, then.

Comment: I need the radio buttons to be checked either 1 at a time or if a already checked button it clicked then it unchecks

Comment: @Lee Isn't that the point? Either you want everything to stay unchecked (using any of the code here) or you want only the button you click to be checked, which is default behavior and doesn't require any scripting.

Comment: @Lee unchecks just that one that was clicked, or both of them?

Comment: its a radio group... only 1 can be checked, but i want to uncheck if its already checked

Comment: ah, you mean you want _nothing_ selected - i.e. make none of the items valid?

Comment: @Lee right, this is a _much_ harder problem.  A radio button's `click` handler _always_ thinks the button is checked and I can't yet figure out a reliable way of telling whether it was _already_ checked.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I have an even more elegant solution:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').mouseup(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).one('click', function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```

It attaches a `mouseup` handler to the radio button. This is because apparently the state of the radio button is already changed somewhere between the `mouseup` and the `click` event. When you release the mouse button, we know the current state of the radio button. *Only* if it is *checked*, we attach a one-time `click` handler to the radio button that unchecks it.

**UPDATE:**

I've made a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/renaatdemuynck/jquery-uncheckable) for this. It also supports clicking on labels and only captures left mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[name=test]').prop('checked', false);`

For jQuery 1.6+ you can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for values like this:

[Fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/8jKJc/18/)

This, of course, assumes that your goal is to tempt users with the prospect of a checked radio button only to deny them.

Comment: Sorry i need it to uncheck only if its checked

Comment: ??? This unchecks anything that's checked, as do the other two solutions. If you only want to modify those that are checked (due to event bindings or something), you can use `$("input[name=test]:checked")`. I don't quite understand what you want to happen otherwise.